# "reducer" is a required argument, and must be a function or an object of functions that can be passed to combineReducers

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I'm writing a test for my component in react js to check if **Download file** comes after button is clicked. My project also includes redux. It is showing error **"reducer" is a required argument, and must be a function or an object of functions that can be passed to combineReducers**

test component

```
const initialStore={}
const store = configureStore(initialStore)

const MockComponent = () => {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <ExpenseList />
      </BrowserRouter>
    </Provider>
  );
};

test('should render "Download file" when button is clicked', () => {
  render(<MockComponent />);
  const buttonElement = screen.getByRole("button");
  userEvent.click(buttonElement);

  const paraElement = screen.getByText(/download file/i);
  expect(paraElement).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

**Main component**

```
const ExpenseList = () => {
  const [premiumBtn, setPremiumBtn] = useState(false);
  const listOfItems = useSelector(state=>state.expense.expenseItems)
  const amount = useSelector(state=>state.expense.amount)
  const dispatch=useDispatch()

  useEffect(() => {
   if(amount>10000){
     setPremiumBtn(true)
   }
  }, [amount]);
    const expenses = listOfItems.map((expense)=>{
        return(
           <ExpenseListShow
           key={expense.id}
           id={expense.id}
           amount={expense.amount}
           category={expense.category}
           description={expense.description}
           />
        )
    })
    const activatePremiumHandler=()=>{
      dispatch(expenseActions.activatePremium())
    }

  return (
    <div>
      {expenses}
      <p>Amount Spent: {amount}</p>
      {premiumBtn && <button onClick={activatePremiumHandler}>Activate Premium</button>}
    </div>
  );
}

export default ExpenseList;
```

Comment: const initialStore={}, the store is empty cause you can't use it.

Comment: how to create a mock store then?

Comment: You've passed an invalid argument to the configureStore function. You should be passing the same (or similar) argument that you use when you configureStore for your actual application. i.e. It should contain your reducers and all the other configuration..

Comment: Where is the code for your redux slice for expenses? The idea is that you would have a slice to define the shared state, reducers, selectors, thunks, and you would export those reducers for use in creating your "store". You are using a selector in your main component, so *where* is that state being defined/mutated?